# New to classes, Unable to verify math problems through them

Tags: java

I'm trying to build a simple math program for an assignment. I've spent over an hour on it but I can't seem to get the equations to verify properly. Everything else seems to work. The problem is that when it comes time to verify the # of questions right, it only ever counts the last one.
So if I got 3/3 right, it will say 1 out of 3 is right. If I get the first two right and the second wrong, it will say 0 out of 3 is right.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ElementaryMath {

    private double num1;
    private double num2;
    private String opType;
    private int numCorrect;
    private int actualAns;

    ElementaryMath(double n1, double n2, String ot){
        num1=n1;
        num2=n2;
        opType=ot;
    }

    public void printQuestion(){
        System.out.println((int)num1 + " " + opType + " " + (int)num2);
    }

    public void checkAnswer(int ans, String op){

        if(op.equals("/")) {
            actualAns = (int) num1 / (int) num2;
            System.out.println("answer is " + actualAns +" "+ ans);
        }
        if(op.equals("*")){
            actualAns = (int) num1 * (int) num2;
            System.out.println("answer is " + actualAns + " " + ans);
        }

        if(actualAns == ans){
            numCorrect++;
        }

    }

    public String numCorr(){
        return ""+numCorrect+"";
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        double n1, n2;
        String op = "";
        int nq, qt, aq;

        System.out.println("Which option would you like?");
        System.out.println("1. Single Digit - One operation");
        System.out.println("2. Two Digit -  One operation.");
        System.out.println("3. Single Digit - Multiple Operations (Mixed operators)");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Please enter your option. (1, 2, or 3): ");
        qt = in.nextInt();
        if(qt==1 || qt==2) {
            System.out.println("Please enter which operator you would like to use: (type / or * )");
            op = in.next();
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the number of questions you would like: ");
        nq = in.nextInt();

        if(qt==1 || qt==2)
        {
        for(int i=0;i<nq;i++) {
            n1 = Math.random() * 9 + 1;
            n2 = Math.random() * 9 + 1;
            ElementaryMath a = new ElementaryMath(n1, n2, op);
            a.printQuestion();
            System.out.println("Please print your answer: ");
            aq = in.nextInt();
            a.checkAnswer(aq, op);
            if(i==(nq-1)) {
                System.out.println("You have successfully answered " + a.numCorr() + " out of " + nq + " questions correctly.");
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: You keep creating a *new* `ElementaryMath` object in each iteration of your loop. Each one starts out with a `numCorrect` value of 0. You need to re-think your design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem was that you needed a static counter variable (numCorrect). Then, you needed to check if the answer given and the answer is correct. Here is the modified code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ElementaryMath {

    private double num1;
    private double num2;
    private String opType;
    private static int numCorrect;
    private int actualAns;

    ElementaryMath(double n1, double n2, String ot){
        num1=n1;
        num2=n2;
        opType=ot;
    }

    public void printQuestion(){
        System.out.println((int)num1 + " " + opType + " " + (int)num2);
    }

    public void checkAnswer(int ans, String op){

        if(op.equals("/")) {
            actualAns = (int) num1 / (int) num2;
            System.out.println("answer is " + actualAns +" "+ ans);
            if(actualAns == ans)
            {
                numCorrect++;
            }
        }
        if(op.equals("*")){
            actualAns = (int) num1 * (int) num2;
            System.out.println("answer is " + actualAns + " " + ans);
            if(actualAns == ans)
            {
                numCorrect++;
            }
        }
    }

    public String numCorr(){
        return ""+numCorrect+"";
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        double n1, n2;
        String op = "";
        int nq, qt, aq;

        System.out.println("Which option would you like?");
        System.out.println("1. Single Digit - One operation");
        System.out.println("2. Two Digit -  One operation.");
        System.out.println("3. Single Digit - Multiple Operations (Mixed operators)");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Please enter your option. (1, 2, or 3): ");
        qt = in.nextInt();
        if(qt==1 || qt==2) {
            System.out.println("Please enter which operator you would like to use: (type / or * )");
            op = in.next();
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the number of questions you would like: ");
        nq = in.nextInt();

        if(qt==1 || qt==2)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<nq;i++) {
                n1 = Math.random() * 9 + 1;
                n2 = Math.random() * 9 + 1;
                ElementaryMath a = new ElementaryMath(n1, n2, op);
                a.printQuestion();
                System.out.println("Please print your answer: ");
                aq = in.nextInt();
                a.checkAnswer(aq, op);
                if(i==(nq-1)) {
                    System.out.println("You have successfully answered " + numCorrect + " out of " + nq + " questions correctly.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This fixes your issues such as miscounting.

Comment: Already solved, but this is another take on it that I can learn from. Thank you for your input!

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are keeping the count of correct answers in an instance variable of your `ElementaryMath` object, but you are creating a new instance of `ElementaryMath` (and hence a new counter) each time you go round the `for` loop.

Comment: I don't know how to create a loop that would generate new instances of the class without knowing the amount of times the questions need to be generated first.

Comment: For example, it needs to be able to generate any number of questions (obviously within reason)

Comment: Nevermind, I got it, I changed the variable numcorrect into something the main method checked, and changed the checkAns method to return a boolean of true or false which it could be checked against.